# bash, can't execute binary file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly

I'm currently trying to learn assembly on my Trisquel distribution (which I guess uses Ubuntu under the hood?). For some reason, I'm stuck on the very first step of creating and executing a assembly snippet.

```
.section data

.section text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $1, %eax # syscall for exiting a program
movl $0, %ebx # status code to be returned
int $0x80
```

When I try to assemble and link it for creating an executable and run the executable, I get something like:

```
> as myexit.s -o myexit.o && ld myexit.o -o myexit
> ./myexit
bash: ./myexit: cannot execute binary file
```

I'm not sure what exactly is going on here. After searching around, it seems that this error usually pops up when trying to execute 32 bit executable on a 64 bit OS or maybe vice-versa which isn't the case for me.

Here is the output of `file` and `uname` command:

```
$ file myexit
myexit: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
$ uname -a
Linux user 2.6.35-28-generic #50trisquel2-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 3 00:54:52 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone help me out in understanding what exactly is going wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: the executable bit is there, right?

Comment: @Uku: Yes, otherwise it normally gives `permission denied` error

Comment: thought so myself, but just checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.section text
```

is incorrect, that creates a section called `text` when you need your code to be in the `.text` section. Replace that with:

```
.data

.text
.globl _start
_start:
  ...
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! After replacing `data` with `.data` and `text` with `.text` the code worked like a charm.